# Scope evaluate time in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, scope

I'm writing a scope that should look for calls with a status of open and any call with a datetime greater than current time.  I'm a bit fuzzy on the syntax, can someone help point me in the right direction.

Example that fails:

```
scope :scheduled_calls, where(:call_status => "open", :transfer_date > Time.now)
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a lambda to evaluate the scope when it's called, as opposed to when the class is loaded.

```
scope :scheduled_calls, lambda { where(["call_status = ? and transfer_date > ?", "open", Time.now]) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scope :scheduled_calls, where("call_status = 'open' and transfer_date > ?", Time.now)
```

Comment: `lambda` should be used here to avoid caching of `Time.now`